# ASP.Net codebehind - get google paid advert info

Tags: asp.net, google-analytics, google-ads-api

I have an ecommerce site written in asp.net. Is there any way from my site code to see when a user was referred to my site from a paid google ad? Note that this should work on any page - not just the search landing page.

[More detail - I can see in google analytics that 20%+ of paid click traffic eventually hits my 'register' page, but then only a small portion actually successfully registers. I want to check how many of these are failing the Captcha check, and hence are likely to be bots rather than real traffic.]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement your solution using the Global Application Class (Global.asax) file. If you implement the `Application_BeginRequest` event along with `Request.Server["HTTP_REFERER"]` or `Request.UrlReferrer` you can know where the current request is coming from, and capture all possible Google Ads domains with it.

```
void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
    string referer = Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_REFERER"];

    if (referer != null && referer.IndexOf("google") > -1)
    { 
        //coming from google
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Google adds a tracking parameter `gclid` to the url. You can intercept that on your page.